# Python: Rounding output of the time module

Tags: python

This is the code I have for measuring how long it took the user to complete the program:

```
start_time = time.time() # Sits at the top of my code
print("%f seconds" % (time.time() - start_time)) # Goes at the bottom of my code
```

My question is, how do I round the output of this to one decimal place? For example, if my output was `3.859639 seconds` how would I present this like: `3.8 Secounds?`

Comment: Ewh, that mistype. I meant to say 3.8 secounds

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `3.9 seconds`?

Comment: So, you want to round down all the time? Instead of rounding 3.859... to 3.9?

Comment: If you need the value rounded, the look into the `round()` function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round. To round down you could subtract 0.5 and then `round()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you've forgotten ".1" before "f". Try this:

```
print("%.1f seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: This works for me, having 3.9 instead of 3.8 won't kill my program so it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive way... multiply out, truncate the rest, then divide again:

```
diff = time.time() - start_time
rounded_down = int(diff * 10) / 10 # = 3.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use round function with second argument as 1

```
start_time = time.time() # Sits at the top of my code
x=round((time.time() - start_time),1)
print x
```